# can't see information on author page that don't have posts

Tags: author, author-template

I have page for each author role, but if the author doesn't have any posts I can't get its variables, because the loop is empty. The page returns empty, no avatar, no author name and bio.

How do I get WordPress to pull out the author variable if there are no posts?

I'm using **hello elementor theme** and **WP User Avatar** plugin.

Comment: You should ask the theme/plugin author.

Comment: I asked them
Their answer was that i use different plugins and they cannot check it for me

Comment: I found this answer but I don't know how and where i need to put this code

global $curauth;
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
echo 'This is the author page of '.$curauth->display_name;